# Set maximum time with UIDatePicker - time mode - swift

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

Is it possible to customise the UIDatePicker in `CountDownTimer` mode to not show the picker values past a certain point? For example if I set it to 2 hours it would only show 2 hours downwards.

Currently I have tried a few techniques but all I have succeeded in is setting the countdown point to a certain value using  `maximumDate`.

```
self.datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.CountDownTimer

//For calculating a date with +30 mins
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let date = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitMinute, value: 30, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil)
    println("30+Mins \(date)")

//Interval for countdownDuration
    let myTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(timeOffset * 60)
    println("myTimeInterval \(myTimeInterval)")

//Tried Methods - countDownDuration sets it to a certain points(in seconds)
        self.datePickerView.countDownDuration = myTimeInterval
        self.datePickerView.maximumDate = date // This doesn't seem to do anything when in using UIDatePickerMode.CountDownTimer
```

I presume a possible way is to use just a UIPicker.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as you say - it's possible to do it yourself with UIPickerView. And that's actually exactly what I did: I built a custom `UIPickerView` subclass for that purpose. It replicates the functionality of UIDatePicker in countDownTimer mode, while adding support to set `maxTimeInterval`.

[image: GSTimeIntervalPicker showcase gif]

You use it like this:

```
GSTimeIntervalPicker *picker = [[GSTimeIntervalPicker alloc] init];
picker.maxTimeInterval = (3600 * 3);    // set the limit
picker.minuteInterval = 5;              // the step. Default is 1 min.
picker.timeInterval = (3600 * 1.5);     // 1 h 30 minutes
picker.onTimeIntervalChanged = ^(NSTimeInterval newTimeInterval) {
    // Use the value
};
```

Available [on GitHub](https://github.com/LukasCZ/GSTimeIntervalPicker) under MIT license. Blog post [here](http://www.glimsoft.com/12/05/meet-gstimeintervalpicker/). I'm sorry it's not in Swift, you will have to convert it yourself.

Comment: how can i do this using Swift 3?

Comment: well, you'd need to convert the source code to Swift yourself. Do you know at least some Obj-C?

Answer (score 0):

First Thing: you don't need a calendar to add 30 minutes to a given date.

There is a constructor that does what you want in one step:

```
NSDate(timeInterval: NSTimeInterval, sinceDate: NSDate)
NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: NSTimeInterval)
```

for me,

```
self.datePickerView.maximumDate = date
```

shows future dates / time greyed out, so the user has some visual hint.

This doesn't mean, a future date / time is not selectable without additional code.

The user can select a greyed out time. You can check in your handler and when some future date is selected, you just set

```
self.datePickerView.date = date
```

as long as you don't call resignFirstResponder(), your date picker scrolls back to now (or any other chosen time) nicely. So the user is not able to select a time in the future with this additional code.

I hope this is near enough to what you need. Future is greyed out instead of invisible and it is not selectable with a little additional code in your handler.